# SignaturePad issue in Customrenderer both Android and IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, signature, signaturepad

I have a signature pad designed in my XAML with the help of custom renderers. I am getting the user's signature and saving the signature as an image successfully. However, even when the user has not signed on the signature, and when I am clicking the Save button, an image is saved as an empty image. Is that any boolean property to know without image touch to set false?

Following renderer am using
https://github.com/15mgm15/Xamarin-Forms-Signature

Comment: check if the `Strokes` property is null.  https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad

Comment: @Jason will check and let you know

Comment: @Jason Currently am using a custom renderer to achieve so there is no Strokes property can I change all the functionality or any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can also judge if the user has completed the signature before saving it. Here's the code snippet below for your reference:

**Xaml:**

```
<controls:SignaturePadView
    x:Name="signatureView"
    StrokeWidth="3"
    StrokeColor="BlackWhite"
    BackgroundColor="Black" />
```

**Code in backend:**

```
if (!signatureView.IsBlank)
{
  // Save signature image
}
else
{
  //display the alert to finish the sign
}
```